# Page reload don't stop in Greasemonkey-Script. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I wrote a script in Greasemonkey to check if a button exists and then click it.
Else to reload the page.

Problem: The Button is found and clicked correctly. The page should not reload anymore but keeps on reloading and reloading.

What could be wrong????

Here is the code of my script:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var zeilen = document.getElementsByClassName('content-card-entry fcb-row fcb-clear');
    for (var i = 0; i < zeilen.length; i++) {
        var zeile = zeilen[i];
        // Zeile mit Block 
        if (zeile.children[0].children[0].innerHTML == "247")

        {

            //Den String der ID auslesen
            var IDString = zeile.children[0].children[0].id;
            //Den Identifikationsstring ctlxxx auslesen
            var ClickID = IDString.substr(42, 5);

            //Den ClickString zusammenbauen
            var anfang = "ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_";
            var ende = "_LinkButton1";
            var clickstring = anfang+ClickID+ende;

            //Den Button suchen
            var element = document.getElementById(clickstring);


            //Wenn der Button vorhanden ist klicken und mir eine Nachricht senden
          
            
            element.click();
            
}
else
 {
  location.reload();
 }
 } 
    
 
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop over a set of elements, and do "click or reload the page" for *each* of them. That means unless *every single one* of those elements is the button you're looking for, you're gonna reload the page.

Put a `return` after `element.click()`, so that your entire function exits if the button is found, and put `location.reload()` after the for loop, so that it is only called if the for loop terminated without returning from the function.

Comment: The more important point is though: Do you understand why it works, and why your code doesn't? If not, I urge you to put come `console.log` and/or `debugger` statements in your code to see what gets executed under which conditions.

Comment: Yes I understand. I had the reload in the loop so it reloads for every "i" when if is not fullfilled. Now i stop the loop when if is fullfilled and the reload is after the loop and not in every single loop. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. I'm happy to see that I'm actually teaching something then, instead of just providing code. :)

Comment: I started "progamming" two weeks ago. That is my first script. I need to learn ;-)